# Exclude observations below a certain threshold in a stacked bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I need to exclude some observations below a certain threshold in   stacked bar chart done with ggplot2.

An example of my dataframe:

[image]

My code:

```
  ggplot(df, aes(x=reorder(UserName,-Nb_Interrogations, sum), y=Nb_Interrogations, fill=Folder)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.5,"line"), legend.position = c(0.8,0.7)) +
  labs(x = "UserName") +
  ylim(0, 95000) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 95000, 10000)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

The problem is that I have many observations (UserName) with low values on the Y axes (Nb_Interrogations). So I'd like to exclude all the UserName below a certain threshold from the barplot, let's say 100.
[image]

I tried with the which function changing my code:

```
ggplot(df[which(df$Nb_Interrogations>100),]aes(x=reorder(UserName,-Nb_Interrogations, sum), y=Nb_Interrogations, fill=Folder)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.5,"line"), legend.position = c(0.8,0.7)) +
  labs(x = "UserName") +
  ylim(0, 95000) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 95000, 10000)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

But it doesn't fit my case since it excludes all the observations below the threshold = 100 that are present in my DF from the general computation changing also the Y axes values. How can I solve this problem? thanks
[image]

Comment: I'm a little unclear on your question, probably because it's hard to guess what your data looks like. Your solution will remove any _individual_ observations where Nb_Interrogations < 100, and the resulting graph is probably correct (i.e., you'd expect changing y values in a stacked bar graph). Are you instead looking to eliminate _total_ values < 100, that is, where the stacked column is <100? If the latter, you may be easier to exclude those values before plotting. A sample of your data would help.

Comment: Hi @phalteman, yes I'm trying to eliminate total values < 100, that is, where the stacked column is <100 for better visualization. I added an extract of the df. thanks

Comment: Thanks for providing a snapshot of your data. However, it's not possible to use that in developing an answer for you. Instead, use `dput(head(yourdata), 20)` and copy and paste the result to provide the first 20 rows of your data (or however many are required to replicate the problem). But I think that gives enough insight to propose a solution (see below).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the simplest solution for you will involve subsetting your data first, and then plotting. Without workable data to test, this is just a theoretical answer, so you may have to adapt for your needs. You can pipe the subsetting and plotting together for ease. Something like this might do the trick for you:

```
df %>%
  group_by(UserName) %>%
  filter(sum(Nb_Interrogations > 100)) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=reorder(UserName,-Nb_Interrogations, sum), y=Nb_Interrogations, fill=Folder)) +
  ## the rest of your plotting code here ##
```